# Why is the output of the AWS CLI list-subscriptions command different than what is shown in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-sns

When I use the AWS CLI's `list-subscriptions` command to list all subscriptions for a particular platform application, I get a much larger number of subscriptions than what is shown in the AWS console.

The `list-subscriptions` command outputs **~160,000** subscription JSON objects and the AWS console shows this:

[image]

Why the big difference?

Comment: Can you post the whole command that you are using?

Comment: That's a lot of subscriptions. Perhaps there is some practical limit or bug in the UI. I'd personally trust the CLI or SDK results in this situation.